# WebStorm IDE is acting funny

Tags: ide, webstorm

For some reason my WebStorm IDE has changed the way I highlight and paste things. Here is an example on the highlighting:

[image]

It doesn't do it line by line anymore, it's literally where I select. And the pasting thing just moves everything over and pastes it in the document in the same format it was copied.

No other software has this issue.

Anyone got any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have enabled a rectangular selection. Check if the **Edit | Column Selection Mode** action is ticked:

[image]